# Discord.JS - Multiple Button Updating

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have an embed with 5 buttons that are by default green, clicking one should turn it red just like toggling a switch on and off.

My issue is how do I change one buttons style while keeping it in the same row.

This is the button row I have created below,

```
const roleSelectionRow = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
            new Discord.MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('rustUpdates')
                .setLabel('Rust')
                .setStyle('SUCCESS'),
            new Discord.MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('gmodUpdates')
                .setLabel('Garrys Mod')
                .setStyle('SUCCESS'),
            new Discord.MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('minecraftUpdates')
                .setLabel('Minecraft')
                .setStyle('SUCCESS'),
            new Discord.MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('fivemUpdates')
                .setLabel('FiveM')
                .setStyle('SUCCESS'),
            new Discord.MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('arma3Updates')
                .setLabel('Arma 3')
                .setStyle('SUCCESS')
        );
```

And this is my `interactionCreate` event (please ignore the mess I'm just trying to make it work before I slim it down and make it better)

```
        client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
        if (!interaction.isButton()) {
            return null
        }

        if (interaction.customId === 'rustUpdates') {
            console.log(interaction.customId.toString())
            if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has(Rust.id)) {
                await interaction.member.roles.remove(Rust)
            } else if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(Rust.id)) {
                await interaction.member.roles.add(Rust)
            }
        }
        if (interaction.customId === 'gmodUpdates') {
            console.log(interaction.customId.toString())
            if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has(GarrysMod.id)) {
                await interaction.member.roles.remove(GarrysMod)
            } else if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(GarrysMod.id)) {
                await interaction.member.roles.add(GarrysMod)
            }
        }
        if (interaction.customId === 'minecraftUpdates') {
            console.log(interaction.customId.toString())
            if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has(Minecraft.id)) {
                await interaction.member.roles.remove(Minecraft)
            } else if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(Minecraft.id)) {
                await interaction.member.roles.add(Minecraft)
            }
        }
        if (interaction.customId === 'fivemUpdates') {
            console.log(interaction.customId.toString())
            if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has(FiveM.id)) {
                await interaction.member.roles.remove(FiveM)
            } else if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(FiveM.id)) {
                await interaction.member.roles.add(FiveM)
            }
        }
        if (interaction.customId === 'arma3Updates') {
            console.log(interaction.customId.toString())
            if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has(Arma3.id)) {
                await interaction.member.roles.remove(Arma3)
            } else if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(Arma3.id)) {
                await interaction.member.roles.add(Arma3)
            }
        }
        await interaction.update({components: [roleSelectionRow, serverJoinRow]})
    })
```

AFAIK there is no direct way of `updating`/`editing` buttons like there is for a message or embed, that's what I've been told at least by a few people in the `D.JS` discord server.

Anyone have any possible ideas of how I could approach making this work? Thank you

Comment: I believe MessageActionRow.components is an array which will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [MrMythical](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15781079/mrmythical) I was able to fix it up to work like a toggle switch.
Please see the updated code below for anyone else struggling with something like this.

```
        client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
        if (!interaction.isButton()) {
            return null
        }

        if (interaction.customId === 'rustUpdates') {
            console.log(interaction.customId.toString())
            if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has(Rust.id)) {
                serverGameUpdates.components[0].setStyle('SUCCESS')
                await interaction.member.roles.remove(Rust)
            } else if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(Rust.id)) {
                serverGameUpdates.components[0].setStyle('DANGER')
                await interaction.member.roles.add(Rust)
            }
        }
        if (interaction.customId === 'gmodUpdates') {
            console.log(interaction.customId.toString())
            if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has(GarrysMod.id)) {
                serverGameUpdates.components[1].setStyle('SUCCESS')
                await interaction.member.roles.remove(GarrysMod)
            } else if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(GarrysMod.id)) {
                serverGameUpdates.components[1].setStyle('DANGER')
                await interaction.member.roles.add(GarrysMod)
            }
        }
        if (interaction.customId === 'minecraftUpdates') {
            console.log(interaction.customId.toString())
            if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has(Minecraft.id)) {
                serverGameUpdates.components[2].setStyle('SUCCESS')
                await interaction.member.roles.remove(Minecraft)
            } else if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(Minecraft.id)) {
                serverGameUpdates.components[2].setStyle('DANGER')
                await interaction.member.roles.add(Minecraft)
            }
        }
        if (interaction.customId === 'fivemUpdates') {
            console.log(interaction.customId.toString())
            if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has(FiveM.id)) {
                serverGameUpdates.components[3].setStyle('SUCCESS')
                await interaction.member.roles.remove(FiveM)
            } else if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(FiveM.id)) {
                serverGameUpdates.components[3].setStyle('DANGER')
                await interaction.member.roles.add(FiveM)
            }
        }
        if (interaction.customId === 'arma3Updates') {
            console.log(interaction.customId.toString())
            if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has(Arma3.id)) {
                serverGameUpdates.components[4].setStyle('SUCCESS')
                await interaction.member.roles.remove(Arma3)
            } else if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(Arma3.id)) {
                serverGameUpdates.components[4].setStyle('DANGER')
                await interaction.member.roles.add(Arma3)
            }
        }
        await interaction.update({components: [serverGameUpdates, serverDiscordLinks]})
    })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).